# scala.xml.pull.XMLEventReader not keeping up with stream

Tags: xml, scala

I'm trying to use the scala.xml.pull.XMLEventReader roughly like so:

```
private val in =
    new XMLEventReader(Source.fromInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()), "utf-8")).buffered
```

Then I iterate over the XML stream with:

```
while (in.hasNext) {
    in.next match { ... }
}
```

The problem here is that the xmleventreader is blocking on "hasNext" and not alerting to new XML tags that I know have arrived (I monitored the stream with TCP Dump.. and can see a <success xmlns="blah"/> tag at the end but still haven't even been notified the previous tag was closed).

I tried this in scala 2.8.0, 2.8.1 and 2.9.0

Is also tried without ".buffered" and without using BufferedInputStream but the results were the same.

Is there any hope or is the XMLEventReader just broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MarkupParser` is broken. When closing a tag, it always gets the next character. Since you are reading from a stream, that blocks until such a character is provided or the stream is closed.

Comment: For reference I'm linking to the bug report: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4599

Comment: It is true, the reader cannot read live TCP streams and is only good for reading from local files really until that bug fix is accepted.